# ionic 2 directives load with lazy load modules

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic 2
global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.1.2
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.0 
Ionic CLI        : 3.1.2
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.1.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.1.2
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.2.1
```

I have two module home and about page module with lazy load features

I create one directive name `testd`. And then I load this directive in two pages with import statement. I got error: You have to create a shared module.

Then I create a directive module only for loading directives

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

    import { TestdDirective } from './testd/testd';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [],
        exports: [
            TestdDirective
        ],
        declarations: [
            TestdDirective
        ],
        providers: [],
    })
    export class DirectivesModule { }
```

And import this module in two page module but directives not working. No errors. Have any idea what I miss?

Comment: Can you post more detail about your code? What does your directive looks like? How do you import it in your other module?